# PHP - Send Form Data from 1 Script to Another

Tags: php, forms, redirect, curl, send

I have a form that sends POST data TO A PHP script. Once processed, i use `Header( Location: 'thankyou.htm")` to redirect user to thank you page.

What I want to do is have PHP script send all form data to another PHP script for further processing. If i do it all in 1 script it takes very long (7-12+ seconds) due to doing PING/POST with another server. See diagram below.
[image]

How do I do it?

```
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$name = $_REQUEST["f_name"];
$website = $_REQUEST["website"];
```

**PS** - Script2 does PING witn a external server to verify data ... this takes up a LONG time. And while this is happening - page is "loading" for user ... which looks bad.

**PSS** - I'm not a programmer - so i'm asking for help here. Please provide some simple "sample code" how to send $name, $email and $website from script 1 to script 2.

Thank you all for helping.

**PS3** why do downvote the question? It's a legitimate problem i have... i even spent 30 minutes making the diagram ... :(

Comment: You can run one script inside another script with include: `include('script2.php');` Reading again, I believe that your issue is time, not functionality. Is that correct?

Comment: @kainaw - that would make script1 execute code from script2 ... i want to separate them to speed things up... instead of include I could just compy/paste code from script2 ...

Comment: Without using AJAX, PHP is "linear".  You need to combine script2 and thankyou somehow.  You can either include script2 at the *end* of the thankyou page, or at the *beginning*, or *before* the thankyou page.  Is it a "big" script, that takes a long time to run? If not, then just incorporate it into the "thankyou" page using `require_once 'script2.php';` (note that the thank you would probably need to be thankyou.php)

Comment: FYI, more context is helpful.  WHAT does script2 do? Does it take a long time? You mention "speed things up".  WHAT are you speeding up?

Comment: @cale_b The question says that script2 takes 7-12 seconds to run. He doesn't want the user to wait for that.

Comment: There are two common ways to do this: 1) Execute (actually use exec) script2 as a command-line program without waiting for it to end (google "php execute without wait"). 2) Make a buffer to store data from script1. Have script 2 always run, looking in the buffer. When there is data sitting there, parse it.

Comment: @cale_b - script2 does PING witn a external server to verify data ... this takes up a LONG time. And while this is happening - page is "loading" for user ... which looks bad.  I will update OG post

Comment: @kainaw - i'm not a programmer ... just an amature website owner ... i don't know how to do that (buffer)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

You can create a curl request in script1, and send the data to script2. Once the data is forwarded, you can redirect your user to the thankyou.htm.

You might want to add a graphic letting the user know that their request is being processed (from a UI/usability standpoint).

```
<?php
// initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// set the options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.myurl.com/script2.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            http_build_query(array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'website' => $website)));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// execute the curl request
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

// close it
curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") {
    //redirect to thankyou.htm
} else {
    //tell the user what went wrong, or something.
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried to understand cURL a while ago, but it does not make sense to me - im not a programmer. Could you provide simple "sample code" how to send $name, $email and $website from script 1 to script 2 with cURL? Thanks

Comment: thank you for code - i will go ahead and test it. In SCRIPT 2 - how do i "accept" or "receive" these variables? same as in script 1? `$email = $_REQUEST["email"];` ... once again, thanks

Comment: This may take just as long though, as curl isn't asynchronous, curl_multi is, but I haven't used that yet. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php has an example for how to call two curl requests asynchronously. You car probably do the same, but eliminate one request, and have your code run a little quicker. Yes it should receive them the same as in script 1.

Comment: so I set "further processing" as per you script, and DON'T get `($server_output == "OK")` .... here is my SCRIPT 2 code (basically for testing it writes variables to CSV file:  

`$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$name = $_REQUEST["f_name"];
$name = $_REQUEST["f_name"];

  $handle = fopen("emaillist.csv", "a");
  fputs($handle, $name . ', ' . $email . ', '. $website . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($handle);`

Comment: What is being returned as the $server_output?